# How to call a Reusable Action that is stored in HP ALM-QC at run time

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, hp-alm

I want to **call a reusable action in my script at run time**.  This **reusable action is stored from HP ALM-QC**, not in my local machine.

See below for the current set-up of my test script:

**The reusable action was called using the Solution Explorer:**

[image: How reusable action was called in the script.]

**Location of the Reusable Action:**

[image: Reusable Action Properties.]

**How it looks like in the test script:**

[image]

Now, what I am trying to do is to call the reusable action directly in the test script. Not by adding it in the Solution Explorer.

Could it be done by using something like:

```
ExecuteFile "[ALM] ..."?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it worked by using `LoadAndRunAction`

**Command Structure:**

If Reusable Action Stored in the HP ALM:

```
LoadAndRunAction "[ALM] Subject\FolderPath\TestScriptName", "ActionName", oneIteration
```

If Reusable Action Stored in the Local Machine:

```
 LoadAndRunAction "C:\FolderPath\TestScriptName", "ActionName", oneIteration
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is [`LoadAndRunAction`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#OV_Supp_Util/Utility_Utility_LoadAndRunAction.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I made it work after couple of tries. I posted the answer.